# Quadratic number field with discriminant $d_K$

Tags: number-theory

Let K be a quadratic number field with discriminant $d_K$.

Why is $K= \mathbb Q(\sqrt(d_K))$ and $\mathbb O_K = \mathbb Z[\frac{d_K+\sqrt{d_K}}{2}]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because quadratic extension means $K$ is a $ \Bbb{Q}$ vector space of dimension 2 with basis $1,x$ ie. $K = \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+bx+c)$ so that $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{b^2-4c})$ with $b,c\in \Bbb{Q}$ and $b^2-4c$ not a square,

Take an integer $m$ such that $(b^2-4c)m^2 \in \Bbb{Z}$, let $n^2$ the largest square dividing it, you get $K = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with $d=(b^2-4c)m^2/n^2\in \Bbb{Z}$ square-free,

> Let $ \tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2},\tau'= \frac{1-\sqrt{d}}{2}$  if $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$,
>
> otherwise $\tau = \sqrt{d},\tau'=-\sqrt{d}$

Then $O_K =\Bbb{Z}[\tau]$ (proof : $u+v\sqrt{d}\in K$ is in $O_K$ iff its minimal polynomial $(X-u-v\sqrt{d})(X-u+v\sqrt{d})$ has integer coefficients iff $u^2-v^2d\in \Bbb{Z},2u\in \Bbb{Z}$)

$d_K=Disc(\tau) = (\tau-\tau')^2= 4d$ if $d\not \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $d_K=d$ if $d\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

In both cases $O_K= \Bbb{Z}[\frac{d_K+\sqrt{d_K}}{2}]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have two additional questins: I've read that $ O_K \cap \mathbb Q = \mathbb Z$ , but why is this true? 2.) In the same line, there is written that $K = $Frac($O_K$) is the quotient field of $O_K$. Why is this true?